# React TinyMCE editor set bbcode content dynamically

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, bbcode

I am using this official component https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/

I want to use this method from documentation https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent in order to define bbcode as content for my editor.

But I get an error:

**this.editor.setContent is not a function**

Here is my code

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';

/**
 * Comment component.
 */

class Comment extends PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.editor.setContent('[b]some[/b] html', { format: 'bbcode' });
  }

  render() {
    return (<Editor
      ref={(editor) => {
        this.editor = editor;
      }}
      apiKey="***"
    />);
  }
}

export default Comment;
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make TinyMCE editor to work with bbcode.
Here is my code:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';

/**
 * Comment component.
 */

class Comment extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { content: 'this is a [url=https://google.com]link[/url]' };
    this.handleEditorChange = this.handleEditorChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleEditorChange(content) {
    this.setState({ content });
  }

  render() {
    return (<Editor
      value={this.state.content}
      onEditorChange={this.handleEditorChange}
      apiKey="***"
      init={{
        menubar: '',
        plugins: 'bbcode link code',
        toolbar: '',
      }}
    />);
  }
}

export default Comment;
```

Answer (score -1):

in tinymce-react the right way to set initial content is:

```
 <Editor
   initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>"    
 />
```

Ref: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/#4replacetheappjsfile

As you can see from [source](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-react/blob/master/src/main/ts/components/Editor.tsx) the method you are seeking for is not exposed in *Editor* component.

Comment: If you had been attentive you would see that I asked about bbcode, not html

Comment: This is not HTML, this is JSX and linked official docs usage is well documented, mate. Editor is a wrapper for tinymce, some methods are managed by props.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to call setContent method from react?

Comment: Mate, if you use the react component you have to pass it by props as I shown.